# Index 0 is out of bounds (must be less than 0) Error when passing realm object through segue

Tags: swift, realm

I have a collectionViewController and detailViewController. I need to pass object from CVController to detail controller via segue. 
Here is the object of a class im passing:

```swift
class FilmCategory: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    var films = List<Film>() 

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
```

and here is Film class:

```swift
class Film: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    var actors = List<String>()
    @objc dynamic var imageURL = ""
    @objc dynamic var duration = 0


    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
```

PS: Im initialising objects from JSON, everything is working fine,
in my collectionViewController im retrieving FilmCategories like this:

```swift
class CategoriesViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let serializer = JSONSerializer()
    var filmCategories: Results<FilmCategory>?


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        registerCellWithNib()
        serializer.serialize(input: URLs.jsonCategoriesURL)
        filmCategories = realm.objects(FilmCategory.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "id",ascending: true)
    }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let categories = filmCategories {
            return categories.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
```

I didn't include cell for row at method, because everything is loading properly in collectionView, but when im clicking on the cell and performing segue,  Im receiving index out of bounds error:

```swift
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: SegueIdentifiers.selectCategory, sender: indexPath)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == SegueIdentifiers.selectCategory , let CategoryIndex = sender as? IndexPath, let filmCategories = filmCategories {
            if let controller = segue.destination as? FilmsViewController {
                controller.currentCategoryIndex = CategoryIndex.row
                controller.category = filmCategories[CategoryIndex.row]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is brief description of my detail view controller class:

```swift
class FilmsViewController: UIViewController {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var currentCategoryIndex = Int()
    @objc dynamic var category: FilmCategory?
```

Every time im performing segue, im receiving error, probably its incorrect way to pass category via segue. Should I just send its index at query it after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sender` in your `prepare(for seque: sender:)` is going to be an instance of UICollectionViewCell (not an index path). You probably want to get a reference to the collection view itself. Its `indexPathsForSelectedItems` property will give you the section and row data you're looking for.

Comment: Interesting thing is, until I started using realm( for offline mode of my app) i populated filmCategories array from API call( using Json on my backend). I had identical classes to my current realm classes and I used same implementation for passing categories. Everything worked perfectly. I was able to cast sender to indexPath and use it to send category according to collectionViewCell

Comment: I believe, although it seems very strange that a cast from a cell to an index path would work! In my own work I usually count on the UICollectionViewDelegate to capture cell-tap events. There is a function called: `collectionView(UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath)` and this function will give you the indexpath to the tapped key. You can then call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` and pass the indexpath in the sender: argument.